# Convert IQueryable<ExposedClass> to IQueryable<InternalClass>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I'm trying to convert `IQueryalbe<ExposedClass>` to `IQueryable<InternalClass>` so that my business layer doesn't get impacted directly when changes might to my 
.edmx file but keep it being able to send me Linq queries in order to don't make one function per query in my data access objects. Everything works fine until I reach this method :

```
public ExposedClass Single(IQueryable<ExposedClass> query)
{
    // The cast is needed, for some reasons Provider isn't resolved correctly from DbSet
    IQueryProvider provider = ((IQueryable)DbContext.SomeGeneratedDbSet).Provider;
    IQueryable<ExposedClass> translated = query.WithTranslations();
    IQueryable<InternalClass> newQuery = provider.CreateQuery<InternalClass>(translated.Expression);
    return new ExposedClass(newQuery.Single());
}
```

When `provider.CreateQuery` is reached, i get an `InvalidCastException` that tells can't cast `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<ExposedClass>` to `IQueryable<InternalClass>` I have tried to encapsulate the `IQueryable<ExposedClass>` or it's Expression but neither worked, how could I fix this/what would be the best way to reach my goal if there's an other?

My provider is EntityFramework6.Npgsql (Nuget package) `InternalClass` is one of the classes generated by EF. I'm using database first.

Comment: What are `ExposedClass` and `InternalClass`? EF can't guess how to convert one arbitrary class to another to generate a query. Have you tried using `Select()` to create the class you want from the one that's loaded? Or use AutoMapper, probably the most popular tool for mapping DTOs to domain objects?

Comment: As for the code, it's far too complicated. It should be just `query.Single()` or `query.Select(ext=>new InternalClass(...));`. If Automapper is used, `var expClass=query.Single(); return Mapper.Map<InternalClass>(expClass);`

Comment: I dont understand how automapper would allow me to redirect the queries recieved by my DAO to the good table from the dbcontext?

Comment: That's the wrong question. The data is loaded by EF. The way the question is written, that suggests that EF is configured to load `ExposedClass` and *that's* what it will load. It can't use entities it doesn't know how to map. If you want to convert that to another type, you'll need to either use `Select()` to create a new InternalClass from the loaded ExposedClass, or use Automapper to do this for you

Comment: BTW you haven't posted the code that produces `query`, the DbContext configuration or the `ExposedClass` and `InternalClass` definitions so it's not possible to say if another way to convert is possible - perhaps there's an inheritance relation between the classes? A common interface? The code posted here doesn't help at all

Comment: The problem for me isnt converting `ExposedClass` to `InternalClass`, i have a converting constructor defined in `ExposedClass` to solve this, my problem is that i'll recieve an `IQueryable<ExposedClass>` (probably generated by something like `ExposedContext.ExposedTable.Where(ec => ec.someProperty == something);`) and i want to query the EF generated `DbSet<InternalClass>` with the same query

Comment: The problem is that you want EF to perform a translation it knows nothing about. Why? How can it know how to do that? How can *we* know how to do that when the code is missing?

Comment: `i have a converting constructor defined in ExposedClass to solve this` you can't have a converting constructor in the class you want to convert *from*. If you have such a constructor in `InternalClass`, a single `.Select(exp=>new InternalClass(exp))` solves the problem. Why should this be any harder? Why should *EF* have to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not really recommended.  When your Entities change, either your DTOs have to change, or you have to adjust the mapping between them.  So it's not obvious that adding this extra layer of complexity is even useful, let alone worth the cost.

Even if your DTOs define the data contract of API consumed by another system, and you need to maintain backwards-compatible versions of that API as you evolve your system, then you should still implement the API methods in terms of your entities, and translate to DTO's "on the edge". The only scneario where what you propose makes sense is if you have an OData API, and the clients are constructing the queries.

Second nothing built-in is going to perform the expression translation for you.  You have to start with a mapping between your Entities and DTO, and consume that not just when projecting back and forth between object instances, but also when translating query expressions.

It looks like AutoMapper might be able to help,  See:

```
Using EntityFramework as an example

dataContext.OrderLines.UseAsDataSource().For<OrderLineDTO>().Where(dto => dto.Name.StartsWith("A"))
```

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html